# How do I create a TEXT column with Go Gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am trying to create a `TEXT` column using Gorm ORM but the column is still created as `VARCHAR(225)`.
Below is the struct I want to migrate to a table.

```
type TextDump struct {
  *gorm.Model
  Title string `gorm:"varchar(50)" json:"title" binding:"required"`
  Text string `gorm:"text" json:"text" binding:"required"`
  Count int `json:"count"`
  ChannelID int `json:"channel_id" binding:"required"`
}
```

The `text` column is created as `VARCHAR` instead of `TEXT`.

Answer (score 5):

Reposting [@Narro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5760975/narro)'s comment here for better discoverability (I too had to check the comments).

You should use the tag name `type` before the column type:

```
type TextDump struct {
  *gorm.Model
  Text string `gorm:"type:text"`
  // ...
}
```

Reference: [Gorm Field Tags](https://gorm.io/docs/models.html#Fields-Tags)

Answer (score 0):

Just create with a blank tag.

```
type Post struct {
  gorm.Model
  Content string ``
}
```

P.S. I'm using Gorm v1.20.12 with Postgres 11.8

Answer (score 0):

```
Title string `gorm:"type:varchar(50)"`
```

Answer (score -1):

```
type TextDump struct {
  *gorm.Model
  Title string `gorm:"size:50" json:"title" binding:"required"`
  Text string `gorm:"text" json:"text" binding:"required"`
  Count int `json:"count"`
  ChannelID int `json:"channel_id" binding:"required"`
}
```

Comment: A better, clearer, answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68096632/1517394